# Cast to ObjectID failed for value at path in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a blog application with mongoose,node and angular where there are two model schemas  involved. One is for the blogs and another is for category. When The blog is created, the category is fetched from the category model. The ideal functionality should be that when the user hits the create blog api, at first a form loads along with a dropdown where the existing category lists are fetched through a get request and each element are a document of the category model having unique ids created with shortId, categoryName as well as mongoose ids. In the dropdown only the categoryName is fetched. Now when the user fills up the form and submit it, in the node controller function the category should save the categoryId not by categoryName so I can later sort multiple blogs having same categoryId. But I'm getting category as undefined when creating the blog. But while doing so it is fetching an error on console: category is undefined

Blog Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let blogSchema = new Schema(
    {
        blogId: {type: String,unique: true,index: true},
        title: {type: String,default: ''},
        category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'},
        imagePath: {type: String,default: '' }})
mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

Category Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var CategorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    categoryId: {
      type: String,unique: true,index: true},
    categoryName: {
      type: String,default: ''
    }})
mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

Blog Create controller function:

```
 let createBlog = (req, res) => {

        CategoryModel.findOne({ 'categoryName': req.body.category }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) { console.log('Error at finding categoryId ::', err); res.send(err) }
            /** If db operation is success findOne will return either document or null, we're only projecting _id */
            if (result) {
                console.log('ZZZZZ'+result.categoryId)
                let blogId = shortid.generate()
                let newBlog = new BlogModel({
                    blogId: blogId,
                    title: req.body.title,
                    category: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result.categoryId), // As result._id will be string needs to convert it to ObjectId()
                    imagePath: req.file.path
                })
                newBlog.save((err, result) => {
                    if (err) { console.log('Error at saving new blog ::', err); res.send(err) }
                    else { console.log('Successfully saved new blog'); res.send(result) }
                })
            } else {
                console.log('No category found for ::', req.body.category)
                res.send('No category found')
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you're passing value `movies` to `category` field in `Blog` model instead of passing a valid `ObjectId()`, you need to log this request `req.body.category` & check what's the value !!

Comment: so how am I supposed to pass the ObjectId() in category field of Blog model?

Comment: what are you getting in `req.body.category` that you wanted to pass to category field ?

Comment: I'm getting Movies

Comment: If you've to store `Movies` as a string in `category` then replace this `category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'},` with `category : {type: String}`

Comment: but I need to pass the the objectId not string since I need to sort out the blogs by category also. please help me

Comment: If you're passing 'Movies' string to current `category` field it won't work, atleast from request you need to get a hex string which can be converted to `ObjectId()` & passed in to `category` field of model `Blog` !! You can not store `Movies` string...

Comment: I'm fetching the 'Movies' string only for the frontend users to select among the categories. I want a functionality where the user selects the string movie but when they save it, it should take the ObjectId

Comment: So then you might need to do a `.find()` on `Category` collection get `ObjectId()` for movie & store it in `category` field of blog collection

Comment: so will it be something like this:   CategoryModel.find({ 'categoryId': req.body.category }, (err, result) => {...}

Comment: yes, then you'll input result to `category`

Comment: please check my above edited code. it's now returning category is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From below error :

```
Cast to ObjectID failed for value "Movies" at path "category" at
```

It's because you're passing a string `Movies` to your category field of Blog model which is actually looking for an `ObjectId()` but not a string,
As you need category's `ObjectId()` for category field then you need to first read it from category collection & save it as category while saving new Blog.

You Blog create controller should look like :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

let createBlog = (req, res) => {
    CategoryModel.findOne({ 'categoryId': req.body.category }, { _id: 1 }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { console.log('Error at finding categoryId ::', err); res.send(err) }
        /** If db operation is success findOne will return either document or null, we're only projecting _id */
        if (result) {
            let blogId = shortid.generate()
            let newBlog = new BlogModel({
                blogId: blogId,
                title: req.body.title,
                category: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id), // As result._id will be string needs to convert it to ObjectId()
                imagePath: req.file.path
            })
            newBlog.save((err, result) => {
                if (err) { console.log('Error at saving new blog ::', err); res.send(err) }
                else { console.log('Successfully saved new blog'); res.send(result) }
            })
        } else {
            console.log('No category found for ::', req.body.category)
            res.send('No category found')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : Did you execute that query on DB & check ?

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : Mean did you test that `findOne` query on Db using same request & response ? Seems like in your code it's returning `null`

Comment: yup I did it and response is throwing no category found while getting undefined in console

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : what do you've in `req.body.category` ? Did you print that & check do types match or not ? Also did you execute on Db directly & getting response document or `null` ?

Comment: req.body.category s returning Movies i.e the categoryName

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : not sure what your issue is, Also `.findOne` doesn't return `undefined` it will return `null` !! check your code & debug it.. somehow it look ok..

Comment: I checked out db directly and it's returning null if I do db.categories.findOne({"categoryId": "Movies"})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207807/discussion-between-chatterjeetridib-and-whoami).

Comment: it's printing ZZZZZzihrNEOP.     zihrNEOP is the categoryId for the category Movies

Comment: yup it's working and generating a all over new objectID. But what if I want to save categoryId in place of creating the new onjectID? Also can you explain me how this { _id: 1 } and mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id) works??

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : So from your blogs model in category field your referring ObjectId() then you need to give _id of category document, So from findOne we’re returning only _id & it will be returned as string which we’re again converting as ObjectId and sending in save to blog model..

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : _id is returned as string from findOne is because ObjectId is not json supported only for mongo, finally if you wanted to save categoryId in blog then you need to return that and also in blogs schema change type to string for category field..

Comment: @chatterjeetridib : what do you mean by parse? Replace _id in projection with categoryId and pass it as it is ( prior to that update blog schema on category field plus that mongoose.types.ObjectId() ) is also not needed..